# when performing SELECT operation how is data read from disk each time ? how to verify data is being read from disk?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Do we need to drop OS cache?
I want to read data from disk not from cache I have disabled

```
1. query_cache_type=OFF
2. query_cache_size=0
```

even then when i perform select operation for Id =2 , innodb_buffer_pool_reads changes . If i select Id=3 no change for innodb_buffer_pool_reads.
How do I read next value from disk? Is there any other way to verify whether data is being read from the disk?

[Edit] Thank you all for your response.

I m trying to perform reverse engineering , want to test the execution speed of a select query without cache . So want to disable all cache and read data from disk?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the data is read from the disk every time. What matters is that the data is the latest available, and the whole point of databases and transactions is to guarantee that.

Comment: Why would you read from disk? Buffer pool keeps the latest value in there, and that's done because it's faster to read from RAM than from disk. Disk serves for permanent storage (D in ACID), so it's a bit silly that you want to enforce reading from disk and forcing your system to come to a grinding halt. MySQL will always give you the latest and fresh value when you issue a `SELECT`. Long story short - you have to do **nothing**. And that's the best scenario, you do nothing and there's no problem.

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve? *Why* do you "want to read data from disk not from cache"?  The MySQL query cache isn't the only cache. (You don't have to disable the entire query cache, you can include the SQL_NO_CACHE option in your statement. We have query_cache set to DEMAND, and manage its usage by including SQL_CACHE option in the specific queries we want to use the cache.)  But that's only one cache. As far as "disk reads" for data blocks, there's also the innodb buffer pool and the OS file system cache that reduce "disk reads". Again, *what problem* are you attempting to solve?

Comment: Thank u for your response.

Comment: Please find the updated query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to completely turn off the Query cache, make both of those settings.

To disable the Query cache for a single `SELECT`, do `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.

But...  The QC is not the only caching mechanism.  For InnoDB, the buffer_pool caches data and indexes.  (MyISAM uses its key_cache and the OS's cache)

Typically, the first time you perform a query (after restarting the server), the disk will need to be hit.  Typically, that query (or similar queries) performed after that will not need to hit the disk.  Because of "caching", MySQL will hit the disk as little as *necessary*.

If some other connection in modifying the data you are about to `SELECT`, do not worry.  MySQL will make sure to change the cached copy and/or the disk copy.  You will always get the *correct* value.

InnoDB does things in "blocks" (16KB, typically about 100 rows).  That is the unit of disk I/O.  Ids 1,2,3 are *probably* in the same block.  Again, MySQL takes care of fetches and changes.  It will *probably* read the block once, cache it for a long time, and eventually write it once, even if there are a lot of changes to the rows in the block.

So how does "Durability" happen?  Magic.  It involves the InnoDB log file and some extra writes that are done to it.  That is another topic; it would take much too long to explain it all.